# how to install shadow_hand in ros electric?

Tags: ros, shadow-robot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Do you know how to install the shadow hand in the roslectric with ubuntu 11.10, i look for it but the installation is for the fuerte.. any idea?

EDIT

```
ose@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-shadow-robot ros-fuerte-sr-visualization ros-fuerte-sr-teleop
[sudo] password for jose: 
Leyendo listas de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
ros-fuerte-shadow-robot ya está en su versión más reciente.
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt-get -f install» para corregirlo:
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 ros-fuerte-sr-teleop : Depende de: ros-fuerte-serial-communication (= 0.1.0-s1347132527~oneiric) pero no va a instalarse
 ros-fuerte-sr-visualization : Depende de: ros-fuerte-shadow-robot-ethercat (= 1.1.0-s1356580893~oneiric) pero no va a instalarse
                               Depende de: ros-fuerte-rqt (= 0.1.6-s1355472514~oneiric) pero no va a instalarse
 skype:i386 : Depende de: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.23) pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libqt4-xml:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libx11-6:i386 pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libxext6:i386 pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libxss1:i386 pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libxv1:i386 pero no va a instalarse
              Depende de: libssl1.0.0:i386 pero no va a instalarse
              Recomienda: sni-qt:i386 pero no va a instalarse
              Recomienda: libasound2-plugins:i386 pero no va a instalarse
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt-get -f install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53819/how-to-install-shadow_hand-in-ros-electric?/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If you don't need the latest version of our stacks, you can always use the [available electric packages](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Shadow%20Robot/electric).

If you need something up to date, you'll have to do a source install using [rosinstall](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall) or [rosws](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall/Tutorials/rosws%20tutorial). Here is a rosinstall file you can use:

```
- bzr:
    uri: 'lp:sr-ros-interface'
    local-name: shadow_robot

- bzr:
    uri: 'lp:sr-ros-interface-ethercat'
    local-name: shadow_robot_ethercat

- bzr:
    uri: 'lp:sr-config'
    local-name: sr_config

- bzr:
    uri: 'lp:sr-visualization'
    local-name: sr_visualization

- bzr:
    uri: 'lp:sr-teleop'
    local-name: sr_teleop
```

Here are a few commands to get you started with this rosinstall file. Copy the code above into a file (let's say `/tmp/shadow_robot.rosinstall`).

Now let's initialise a ROS workspace (we'll create it in `~/shadow`):

```
mkdir ~/shadow
source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
rosws init ~/shadow /opt/ros/electric
```

You now have an empty workspace, we'll add the rosinstall file to it and fetch the latest revision of the code:

```
source ~/shadow/setup.bash
rosws merge /tmp/shadow_robot.rosinstall
rosws up
```

You should now have a workspace containing the different stacks you need. Don't forget to source the correct setup.bash (you should probably add the line below to the ~/.bashrc)

```
source ~/shadow/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-02-04**:
i was trying install an overlay of shadow, but it install ros fuerte, on my opt of course with shadow robot inside. really i don't know how to use  bzr, and uri.

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2013-02-04**:
i need to install the fuerte' s version in a different workspace, i run rosws set.... but i dont know wich web site direction i have to use

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2013-02-04**:
To install the fuerte version, you simply need to do: 'sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-shadow-robot ros-fuerte-sr-visualization ros-fuerte-sr-teleop'

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2013-02-05**:
i try it, but i get a few errors, look in the edit what i gets

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2013-02-05**:
From what I understand, your ubuntu install is a bit messed up? Some packages have probably not finished to install or something like this. Did you run the "sudo apt-get install -f" as suggested?

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2013-02-05**:
yes, i did it but i obtain the same error

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-02-05**:
Yes it's works the installation on this way. Thnks a lot Ugo.

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2013-02-05**:
excellent. Could you please mark the answer as being correct to close this thread?

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-02-06**:
the installation was succesfull, but i'm having a problem. i spawn the hand on gazebo, but when i connect the glove to prove it, the hand on gazebo don't move. maybe do you now what it is?

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2013-02-06**:
You should open a new thread for this question. I can't know what is happening without more data (on which topics are you publishing, which command did you use to start the hand, can you move the joints from the command line, etc....)

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-02-07**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/54624/shadow_hand-spawn-on-gazebo-electric-dont-move/